# XML Serializer serializing a Class that extend List

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have a c# projects that contains interface and classes that extend that interface. Apprently, Serializer does not like Interface
So, I have to create a collection class that extend List, this works, but I need to exclude the List root. Please find the code sample below

```
public interface ICreature

[XmlRoot("Creature")]
public class Man : ICreature

[XmlRoot("Creature")]
public class Alien : ICreature

public class CreatureCollection : List<ICreature>, IXmlSerializable
{
        public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema() { return null; }

        public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
        {

        }

        public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
        {
            foreach (ICreature aCreature in this)
            {
                XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(aCreature.GetType());
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, aCreature);
            }
        }
}

public class Something{
    ...
    public CreatureCollection{get;set;}
}


public void main(){
    Something sm = new Something();

    sm.CreatureCollection.Add(new Alien());
    sm.CreatureCollection.Add(new Man());
}
```

XML OUTPUT:

```
<Something>
    <CreatureCollection>
        <Creature></Creature>
        <Creature></Creature>
    </CreatureCollection>
</Someting>
```

Output Needed:

```
<Something>
        <Creature></Creature>
        <Creature></Creature>
</Someting>
```

Please help!... Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Add XmlElement like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreatureCollection creatures = new CreatureCollection() { creatures = new List<string>() { "", "", "" } };
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(builder);
            XmlWriter xWriter = XmlWriter.Create(writer);
            creatures.WriteXml(xWriter);

        }
    }



    public class CreatureCollection : List<string>, IXmlSerializable
    {
        public List<string> creatures { get; set; }

        public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema() { return null; }

        public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
        {

        }

        public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
        {
            Something something = new Something() { creatures = new List<string>() };
            something.creatures.AddRange(creatures);

            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Something));
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, something);
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot("Something")]
    public class Something
    {
        [XmlElement("Creature")]
        public List<string> creatures { get; set; }
    }


}
​
```

Comment: I could not use List<ICreature> without CreatureCollection in Something. Default xml serializer does not like to serialize interface. It will throw an error.

Comment: I need to put CreatureCollection inside Something because it is supposed to be part of Something. And also, wouldn't I lose all my content in Something, if you instantiate Something in write xml function.  Say the Something has other properties.